# XSLT sort in conjunction with preceding-sibling::

Tags: xslt, sorting

Within a foreach loop i want to use preceding-sibling::

```
<for-each..>
    <xsl:sort select="type"/>
    <xsl:when test="preceding-sibling::data[1]/type != type
```

the problem is that "type" within the foreach is compared with a unsorted preceding-sibling
e.g.

```
data1/type = 1 
data2/type = 2
data3/type = 1
```

would compare in the second loop silbling=2 (original unsorted) and type=1 (since it is sorted)

is there a way around it?

UPDATE: my intention is the following

```
before             after
data/type2         type1 value1
data/type1         type1 value2 
data/type1         and speaking in HTML a spacer here (I compare type2:value to preceding-sibling value
data/type2         type2 value1
                   type2 value2
```

I have an unsorted list of addresses where the type is a town and I need a HTML Table sorted by town and to do some stuff depending on the values and other fields (that part is working, but since the comparison with preceding-sibling is not working in a sorted for-each, I got the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to group the data elements by type? Let us know what you're trying to do and we can probably help out (as @Michael Kay said).

One option (in XSLT 2.0 or with the node-set extension) is to sorted-copy the data elements to a new variable, then run your `xsl:for-each` on the nodeset in that new variable. Then the preceding-sibling relationship will reflect the sorted order.

Comment: I would like to sort the nodes by data/type and use it afterwards. How would I make a sorted copy of that node?

Answer (score 4):

This solution now works for me:

```
    <xsl:variable name="sortedcopy">
      <xsl:for-each select="node1/node2/node3/data">
        <xsl:sort select="type" order="ascending"/>
        <xsl:copy-of select="current()"/>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="relItems" select="MSXML:node-set($sortedcopy)" />
    <xsl:for-each select="$relItems/data">
      <xsl:if test="not(preceding-sibling::data[1]/id = id)">
        <hr/>
      </xsl:if>
      <xsl:value-of select="val"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: Glad the suggestion helped. I do think, as each of the answerers indicated, you'd have better performance if you used the recommended grouping features, such as Meunchian.

Comment: [node-set()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hz88kef0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is a proprietary function and isn't part of the [XSL 1.0 standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt), so this won't be portable.

Answer (score 2):

The relationships of nodes to each other - parent, child, sibling, etc, are not changed by sorting. You can look at employees in order of date-of-birth, but they still have the same parents, children, and siblings as they did in the original tree - because they are still nodes in the original tree.

So you've said how you want to solve your problem, and its not going to work. Next step is to tell us what the problem is.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: I would claim that "your question is incoherent and this is why" is an answer. It's not a solution to the OP's problem, but it's an answer to their question.

Comment: If anyone else, like me, ends up here via google, Michael Kay provided an answer to a similiar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42806139/using-preceding-sibling-with-with-xslsort).

Answer (score 1):

Since XSLT guarantees that elements with equal sort keys will appear in document order, you can replace

```
<xsl:when test="preceding-sibling::data[1]/type != type">
```

with

```
<xsl:when test="not(preceding::data/type = type)">
```

to check if the current node is the first node in the document (and therefore, in the sorted set) with its type. (Note that I am using `preceding` instead of `preceding-sibling`, since I do not know if all your data elements will be siblings in the original document.)

If performance is an issue, you could also use `xsl:key`. Another solution is grouping (using Muenchian grouping in XSLT 1.0 and `xsl:for-each-group` in XSLT 2.0).

Comment: The replacement did not work for me. The first group is generated as expected (`<group><data type="type1" value="v1"/><data type="type1" value="v2"/></group>`) but the remaining groups are duplicated (`<group><data type="type2" value="v1"/></group> <group><data type="type2" value="v2"/></group>` instead of the expected `<group><data type="type2" value="v1"/><data type="type2" value="v2"/></group>`).