# Using node-set with Antenna House XSL-FO XSLT

Tags: xslt, xsl-fo, node-set, antenna-house

I would like to use node-set() in Antenna House so I can access preceding-siblings in a sorted list. (I'm trying to follow this example: [[using preceding-sibling with with xsl:sort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42806139/using-preceding-sibling-with-with-xslsort][1]))

I'm not sure what the syntax is for declaring the namespace to access `node-set()`. AH is not giving any errors, but my call to `node-set()` fails. I've tried:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"  xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format"
                xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" extension-element-prefixes="msxsl" version="1.0">
```

Here is the XML:

```
<illustratedPartsCatalog>
        <figure id="fig1">...</figure>
        <catalogSeqNumber assyCode="00" figureNumber="01" indenture="0" item="000" itemVariant="A" subSubSystemCode="0" subSystemCode="0" systemCode="00">
<itemSeqNumber itemSeqNumberValue="000">
<quantityPerNextHigherAssy>XX</quantityPerNextHigherAssy>
<partRef manufacturerCodeValue="00000" partNumberValue="11111-111">
</partRef>
<partSegment>
<itemIdentData>
<descrForPart>VALVE ASSEMBLY</descrForPart></itemIdentData>
</partSegment><applicabilitySegment><usableOnCodeAssy>X</usableOnCodeAssy>
</applicabilitySegment></itemSeqNumber></catalogSeqNumber>
        <catalogSeqNumber>...</catalogSeqNumber>
        <catalogSeqNumber>...</catalogSeqNumber>
        <catalogSeqNumber>...</catalogSeqNumber>
        <catalogSeqNumber>...</catalogSeqNumber>
        <figure id="fig2">...</figure>
        <catalogSeqNumber>...</catalogSeqNumber>
        <catalogSeqNumber>...</catalogSeqNumber>
        <catalogSeqNumber>...</catalogSeqNumber>
        <catalogSeqNumber>...</catalogSeqNumber>
        <catalogSeqNumber>...</catalogSeqNumber>
    </illustratedPartsCatalog>
```

XSLT:

```
    <xsl:variable name="sortedCSN">
            <xsl:for-each select="illustratedPartsCatalog/catalogSeqNumber">
                <xsl:sort select="concat(itemSeqNumber/partRef/@partNumberValue, @figureNumber,@item)"/>
                <xsl:copy-of select="." />
            </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:template name="SortParts2" >
            <xsl:for-each select="msxsl:node-set($sortedCSN)/catalogSeqNumber">
                <xsl:sort select="concat(itemSeqNumber/partRef/@partNumberValue, @figureNumber,@item)"/>
                <xsl:call-template name="catalogSeqNumber-NI">
                    <xsl:with-param name="figNo" select="concat(@figureNumber,@figureNumberVariant)"/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="prfigNo" select="concat(preceding-sibling::catalogSeqNumber/@figureNumber,preceding-sibling::catalogSeqNumber/@figureNumberVariant)" />
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="catalogSeqNumber-NI">
        <xsl:param name="figNo"/>
        <xsl:param name="prfigNo" />        
            <fo:table-row keep-together.within-page="always" wrap-option="wrap">
                <fo:table-cell xsl:use-attribute-sets="table.cell.padding" text-transform="uppercase" wrap-option="wrap">
                    <fo:block wrap-option="wrap">
                        <xsl:value-of select=" ./itemSeqNumber/partRef/@partNumberValue"/>
                    </fo:block>
                </fo:table-cell>
                <fo:table-cell  xsl:use-attribute-sets="table.cell.padding" text-align="start">
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="$figNo">
                            <fo:block>
                                <xsl:text> </xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="$figNo"/><xsl:text> </xsl:text> <xsl:value-of select="$prfigNo"/>
                            </fo:block>
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:otherwise>
                                <fo:block />
                        </xsl:otherwise>
                    </xsl:choose>
                </fo:table-cell>

                <fo:table-cell  xsl:use-attribute-sets="table.cell.padding" text-align="start">
                    <fo:block>
                        <xsl:if test="./itemSeqNumber/partLocationSegment/notIllustrated">
                            <xsl:text>-</xsl:text>
                        </xsl:if>

                        <xsl:choose>
                            <xsl:when test="@item">
                                <xsl:variable name="itemNo">
                                    <xsl:call-template name="suppressZero" >
                                        <xsl:with-param name="pText" select="@item"/>
                                    </xsl:call-template>
                                </xsl:variable>
                                <xsl:text>&#160;</xsl:text>
                                <xsl:value-of select="concat($itemNo,@itemVariant)"/>
                            </xsl:when>
                            <xsl:otherwise />
                        </xsl:choose>
                    </fo:block>
                </fo:table-cell>

                <fo:table-cell xsl:use-attribute-sets="table.cell.padding">
                    <fo:block>
                        <xsl:value-of select="./itemSeqNumber/quantityPerNextHigherAssy"/>
                    </fo:block>
                </fo:table-cell>
            </fo:table-row>
        </xsl:template>
```

Comment: Could you show the entire XSLT as a single stylesheet? What processor do you perform the transformation with (Java with default/Xalan, Saxon, .NET) and what's the exact error message?

Comment: There is no `axf:node-set()` function.  When trying to use `axf:node-set()`, I would expect that you got an error message indicating that the function does not exist.

Comment: The text error was caused by a stray text character that was outside the template. I'm using EditPad Pro and Antenna House 6.2

Answer (score 1):

I think the default for Antenna House on Windows is to use MSXML so the attempt with `xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"` is fine as far as using the `node-set` extension function.

I think you simply need to change the XSLT to

```
    <xsl:variable name="sortedCSN">
            <xsl:for-each select="illustratedPartsCatalog/catalogSeqNumber">
                <xsl:sort select="concat(itemSeqNumber/partRef/@partNumberValue, @figureNumber,@item)"/>
                <xsl:copy-of select="." />
            </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:variable>

<xsl:template name="SortParts2" >
        <xsl:for-each select="msxsl:node-set($sortedCSN)/catalogSeqNumber">
            <xsl:sort select="concat(itemSeqNumber/partRef/@partNumberValue, @figureNumber,@item)"/>
            <xsl:call-template name="catalogSeqNumber-NI">
                <xsl:with-param name="figNo" select="concat(@figureNumber,@figureNumberVariant)"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="prfigNo" select="concat(preceding-sibling::catalogSeqNumber/@figureNumber,preceding-sibling::catalogSeqNumber/@figureNumberVariant)" />
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
```

to make sense with the input you have shown (as far as you have shown it, can't judge all those `xsl:sort` attempts without seeing the data to be sorted).

On the other hand, if you get errors about the stylesheet not being correct XSLT or XML, you would better show us a minimal but complete stylesheet allowing us to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thank you, I tried your suggestion and SortParts2 is still failing. SortParts2 is being called from context node IllustratedPartsCatalog if that helps.