# Using XSLT to create groups for a slideshow

Tags: xml, xslt, grouping, xslt-2.0

This seems like an easy thing and yet I cannot find an example anywhere.

I have a list of items, let's say the list has 34 items.

```
<item>
    <title></title>
    <url></url>
    <date></date>
</item>
<item>...</item>
<item>...</item>
<item>...</item> etc.
```

I want to sort the items by date, then create groups of ten and then wrap them in a slider tag
while processing each item in the slide to a list. Giving me three groups of ten items and a fourth slide of 4 items. Giving the output below:

```
 <slide>
     <ul>    
        <li item 1>Title | Date | Url </li item 1>
        <li item 2>Title | Date | Url </li item 1>
        <li item 3>Title | Date | Url </li item 1>
        <li items 4-10>... etc..
     </ul>    
 </slide>
```

I have code that works, but what happens is that it changes the sort order, and I'm not sure why. If I output the list after the sort, the list is ordered correctly, but once it creates the groups the items in each group do not retain their position. (assuming $group-size=10)

```
<xsl:for-each select="$itemContent/item">
                <xsl:sort select="pub-date" order="descending"/>
                <xsl:if test="position() mod $group-size = 1">
                    <div class="item">
                        <xsl:if test="position()=1">
                            <xsl:attribute name="class">item active</xsl:attribute>
                        </xsl:if>
                        <ul>
                            <xsl:apply-templates select=".|following-sibling::item[position() &lt; $group-size]" mode="list"/>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </xsl:if>

            </xsl:for-each>

    <xsl:template match="item">
        <xsl:if test="position() mod $group-size = 1">
            <ul>
                <xsl:apply-templates select=".|/following::item[position() &lt; $group-size]" mode="list"/>
            </ul>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="item" mode="list">
        <li class="{position()}">
            <strong><a href="{url}"><xsl:value-of select="title" /> | <xsl:value-of select="position()" /></a></strong><br/>
            <xsl:value-of select="format-date(ou:get-xsdate(pub-date),'[FNn] [MNn] [D],  [Y]', 'en', (), ())" />
        </li>
    </xsl:template>
```

Anyone know a better way to do this? Maybe using "group-by" or structing something differently?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sort the items with e.g.

```
<xsl:variable name="sorted-items" as="element(item)*">
  <xsl:perform-sort select="$itemContent/item">
    <xsl:sort select="pub-date" order="descending"/>
  </xsl:perform-sort>
</xsl:variable>
```

then use positional grouping

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="$sorted-items" group-by="(position() - 1) idiv 10">
  <ul>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()" mode="list"/>
  </ul>
</xsl:for-each-group>
```

You haven't provided any sample data for which you said that the code produces no results, but I have now tried to create a sample and incorporate above snippets into a full stylesheet and have created the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">

    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="items">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:variable name="itemContent" select="."/>
            <xsl:variable name="sorted-items" as="element(item)*">
                <xsl:perform-sort select="$itemContent/item">
                    <xsl:sort select="pub-date" order="descending"/>
                </xsl:perform-sort>
            </xsl:variable>
            <xsl:for-each-group select="$sorted-items" group-by="(position() - 1) idiv 10">
                <ul>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()" mode="list"/>
                </ul>
            </xsl:for-each-group>           
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="item" mode="list">
        <li class="{position()}">
            <strong><a href="{url}"><xsl:value-of select="title" /> | <xsl:value-of select="position()" /></a></strong><br/>
            <xsl:value-of select="format-date(pub-date,'[FNn] [MNn] [D],  [Y]', 'en', (), ())" />
        </li>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When I run that against some generated sample data

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<items>
    <item>
        <title>item 1</title>
        <pub-date>2017-07-30+02:00</pub-date>
        <url>http://example.com/search?1</url>
    </item>
    <item>
        <title>item 2</title>
        <pub-date>2017-08-04+02:00</pub-date>
        <url>http://example.com/search?2</url>
    </item>
    <item>
        <title>item 3</title>
        <pub-date>2017-08-06+02:00</pub-date>
        <url>http://example.com/search?3</url>
    </item>
    <item>
        <title>item 4</title>
        <pub-date>2017-08-01+02:00</pub-date>
        <url>http://example.com/search?4</url>
    </item>
    <item>
        <title>item 5</title>
        <pub-date>2017-07-29+02:00</pub-date>
        <url>http://example.com/search?5</url>
    </item>
    <item>
        <title>item 6</title>
        <pub-date>2017-08-14+02:00</pub-date>
        <url>http://example.com/search?6</url>
    </item>
    <item>
        <title>item 7</title>
        <pub-date>2017-07-31+02:00</pub-date>
        <url>http://example.com/search?7</url>
    </item>
    <item>
        <title>item 8</title>
        <pub-date>2017-08-05+02:00</pub-date>
        <url>http://example.com/search?8</url>
    </item>
    <item>
        <title>item 9</title>
        <pub-date>2017-08-09+02:00</pub-date>
        <url>http://example.com/search?9</url>
    </item>
    <item>
        <title>item 10</title>
        <pub-date>2017-08-15+02:00</pub-date>
        <url>http://example.com/search?10</url>
    </item>
    <item>
        <title>item 11</title>
        <pub-date>2017-08-12+02:00</pub-date>
        <url>http://example.com/search?11</url>
    </item>
    <item>
        <title>item 12</title>
        <pub-date>2017-08-07+02:00</pub-date>
        <url>http://example.com/search?12</url>
    </item>
    <item>
        <title>item 13</title>
        <pub-date>2017-07-25+02:00</pub-date>
        <url>http://example.com/search?13</url>
    </item>
    <item>
        <title>item 14</title>
        <pub-date>2017-08-03+02:00</pub-date>
        <url>http://example.com/search?14</url>
    </item>
    <item>
        <title>item 15</title>
        <pub-date>2017-08-08+02:00</pub-date>
        <url>http://example.com/search?15</url>
    </item>
    <item>
        <title>item 16</title>
        <pub-date>2017-08-11+02:00</pub-date>
        <url>http://example.com/search?16</url>
    </item>
    <item>
        <title>item 17</title>
        <pub-date>2017-08-02+02:00</pub-date>
        <url>http://example.com/search?17</url>
    </item>
    <item>
        <title>item 18</title>
        <pub-date>2017-08-16+02:00</pub-date>
        <url>http://example.com/search?18</url>
    </item>
    <item>
        <title>item 19</title>
        <pub-date>2017-08-17+02:00</pub-date>
        <url>http://example.com/search?19</url>
    </item>
    <item>
        <title>item 20</title>
        <pub-date>2017-07-26+02:00</pub-date>
        <url>http://example.com/search?20</url>
    </item>
    <item>
        <title>item 21</title>
        <pub-date>2017-08-10+02:00</pub-date>
        <url>http://example.com/search?21</url>
    </item>
    <item>
        <title>item 22</title>
        <pub-date>2017-07-28+02:00</pub-date>
        <url>http://example.com/search?22</url>
    </item>
    <item>
        <title>item 23</title>
        <pub-date>2017-07-27+02:00</pub-date>
        <url>http://example.com/search?23</url>
    </item>
    <item>
        <title>item 24</title>
        <pub-date>2017-08-13+02:00</pub-date>
        <url>http://example.com/search?24</url>
    </item>
</items>
```

Saxon 9.7 HE outputs

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<items>
   <ul>
      <li class="1">
         <strong>
            <a href="http://example.com/search?19">item 19 | 1</a>
         </strong>
         <br/>Thursday August 17,  2017</li>
      <li class="2">
         <strong>
            <a href="http://example.com/search?18">item 18 | 2</a>
         </strong>
         <br/>Wednesday August 16,  2017</li>
      <li class="3">
         <strong>
            <a href="http://example.com/search?10">item 10 | 3</a>
         </strong>
         <br/>Tuesday August 15,  2017</li>
      <li class="4">
         <strong>
            <a href="http://example.com/search?6">item 6 | 4</a>
         </strong>
         <br/>Monday August 14,  2017</li>
      <li class="5">
         <strong>
            <a href="http://example.com/search?24">item 24 | 5</a>
         </strong>
         <br/>Sunday August 13,  2017</li>
      <li class="6">
         <strong>
            <a href="http://example.com/search?11">item 11 | 6</a>
         </strong>
         <br/>Saturday August 12,  2017</li>
      <li class="7">
         <strong>
            <a href="http://example.com/search?16">item 16 | 7</a>
         </strong>
         <br/>Friday August 11,  2017</li>
      <li class="8">
         <strong>
            <a href="http://example.com/search?21">item 21 | 8</a>
         </strong>
         <br/>Thursday August 10,  2017</li>
      <li class="9">
         <strong>
            <a href="http://example.com/search?9">item 9 | 9</a>
         </strong>
         <br/>Wednesday August 9,  2017</li>
      <li class="10">
         <strong>
            <a href="http://example.com/search?15">item 15 | 10</a>
         </strong>
         <br/>Tuesday August 8,  2017</li>
   </ul>
   <ul>
      <li class="1">
         <strong>
            <a href="http://example.com/search?12">item 12 | 1</a>
         </strong>
         <br/>Monday August 7,  2017</li>
      <li class="2">
         <strong>
            <a href="http://example.com/search?3">item 3 | 2</a>
         </strong>
         <br/>Sunday August 6,  2017</li>
      <li class="3">
         <strong>
            <a href="http://example.com/search?8">item 8 | 3</a>
         </strong>
         <br/>Saturday August 5,  2017</li>
      <li class="4">
         <strong>
            <a href="http://example.com/search?2">item 2 | 4</a>
         </strong>
         <br/>Friday August 4,  2017</li>
      <li class="5">
         <strong>
            <a href="http://example.com/search?14">item 14 | 5</a>
         </strong>
         <br/>Thursday August 3,  2017</li>
      <li class="6">
         <strong>
            <a href="http://example.com/search?17">item 17 | 6</a>
         </strong>
         <br/>Wednesday August 2,  2017</li>
      <li class="7">
         <strong>
            <a href="http://example.com/search?4">item 4 | 7</a>
         </strong>
         <br/>Tuesday August 1,  2017</li>
      <li class="8">
         <strong>
            <a href="http://example.com/search?7">item 7 | 8</a>
         </strong>
         <br/>Monday July 31,  2017</li>
      <li class="9">
         <strong>
            <a href="http://example.com/search?1">item 1 | 9</a>
         </strong>
         <br/>Sunday July 30,  2017</li>
      <li class="10">
         <strong>
            <a href="http://example.com/search?5">item 5 | 10</a>
         </strong>
         <br/>Saturday July 29,  2017</li>
   </ul>
   <ul>
      <li class="1">
         <strong>
            <a href="http://example.com/search?22">item 22 | 1</a>
         </strong>
         <br/>Friday July 28,  2017</li>
      <li class="2">
         <strong>
            <a href="http://example.com/search?23">item 23 | 2</a>
         </strong>
         <br/>Thursday July 27,  2017</li>
      <li class="3">
         <strong>
            <a href="http://example.com/search?20">item 20 | 3</a>
         </strong>
         <br/>Wednesday July 26,  2017</li>
      <li class="4">
         <strong>
            <a href="http://example.com/search?13">item 13 | 4</a>
         </strong>
         <br/>Tuesday July 25,  2017</li>
   </ul>
</items>
```

Comment: That yields the following error: Problem during transform: A sequence of more than one item is not allowed as the value of variable $sorted-items (, , ...) ;

doesn't like the first line.

Comment: Now fixed, shame on me for not having written the right sequence type the first time, shame on you for not providing data to test because then I would probably have tested the code before posting :)

Comment: OK, so strangely, that was producing no results, but when I remove the as="element(item)*"
It works perfectly.
Further research into why this works led me to this thread - [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42806139/using-preceding-sibling-with-with-xslsort%3C/p%3E)
about position and referencing the position after being sorted and why/how that works

Comment: It should work as suggested with `as="element(item)*"`, I have added a sample demonstrating that. If you got an empty output then somehow between the sorting and grouping you have used the wrong selection. The suggested positional grouping of the sorted population does not depend on or require creating new nodes.