# Using following and preceding after sorting xml in xslt 1.0

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I'm trying to pick up the next record/node using xslt after I've done a sort on the data. I know it's possible to pick up the following / preceding nodes, but it doesn't work with a sort:

My data looks like:

```
<Export>
<Record>
    <EmployeeNumber>17177006</EmployeeNumber>
    <Punch_nethours>0.25</Punch_nethours>
    <TimeStartRaw>02.03.2020</TimeStartRaw>
    <TimeStartRaw1>08:00</TimeStartRaw1>
    <TimeEndRaw>08:15</TimeEndRaw>
</Record>
<Record>
    <EmployeeNumber>17177006</EmployeeNumber>
    <Punch_nethours>0.25</Punch_nethours>
    <TimeStartRaw>02.03.2020</TimeStartRaw>
    <TimeStartRaw1>11:00</TimeStartRaw1>
    <TimeEndRaw>11:15</TimeEndRaw>
</Record>
<Record>
    <EmployeeNumber>17177006</EmployeeNumber>
    <Punch_nethours>0.25</Punch_nethours>
    <TimeStartRaw>03.03.2020</TimeStartRaw>
    <TimeStartRaw1>08:00</TimeStartRaw1>
    <TimeEndRaw>08:15</TimeEndRaw>
</Record>
```

I will have multiple records for a particular day, ultimately I'm looking to transpose this into 1 line of data for each employee for each day - I could have up to 3 Records per day. My xslt is sorting the data:

```
    <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="Export/Record">
        <xsl:sort select="EmployeeNumber" order="ascending"/>
        <xsl:sort select="concat(substring(TimeStartRaw,7,4),substring(TimeStartRaw,4,2),substring(TimeStartRaw,1,2))" order="ascending"/>

        <xsl:sort select="translate(TimeStartRaw1,':','')" order="ascending"/>

    >>> <xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::Record[1]/EmployeeNumber"/> <<<

        <xsl:variable name="this_person">
           <xsl:value-of select="EmployeeNumber"/>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:variable name="this_day">
           <xsl:value-of select="TimeStartRaw"/>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:value-of select="sum(//Record[EmployeeNumber = $this_person and TimeStartRaw = $this_day]/Punch_nethours)"/>
```

While the sort works, the following-sibling picks up the unsorted next record from the current value. How do I pick up the next sorted node? I'm using xslt1.0 I could do it in c#, but would prefer a native solution. Anyone any ideas - I've hunted around for a solution, but it seems that the data sets are all a bit different to mine which means it's easier to figure out the next record.

Comment: Do the sorting inside of a variable where you store the nodes, then, with XSLT 1 restriction, convert the variable with `exsl:node-set($var)` back into a node-set and process the node-set, in that node-set your preceding/following-sibling navigation should operate on the sorted nodes and give you the result you want.

Comment: This seems more like a **grouping** problem than a sorting one. If you employ [the standard grouping method for XSLT 1.0](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html), you will not need to look for siblings in a sorted set.

Comment: I agree with @michael.hor257k. It would also be easier to understand and suggest alternatives if you provided a more complete example of the code and example of the desired output.

Comment: @MartinHonnen - That has worked a treat thank you. I created 2 variables, one stores the original, one stores the sorted and then I step through the sorted records - fab.

Comment: It looks as if you encountered that problem some years ago https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42806139/using-preceding-sibling-with-with-xslsort.